# How can I set the schema in a trigger with a parameter?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, triggers, liquibase

Here I am setting the schema that is using liquibase changeset in a Java/Spring.
Until the moment it has worked with the table/key creation. But it doesn't work on custom SQL.

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("dataSource")
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:META-INF/liquibase/application-changes.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts("default"); 
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(databaseProperties.getJdbcSchema());
    return liquibase;
}
```

Now I need to manage large objects in Postgresql, so I want to add the following changeset. But I am having problems as it is not using the parameter, so I had to add "my_schema" in the SQL file. Does anybody knows a workaround or solution for this?

```
<changeSet id="xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-postgres" runInTransaction="true" failOnError="true"
    onValidationFail="HALT" dbms="postgresql">
    <sql >
        CREATE TRIGGER t_table BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON my_schema.table
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_schema.lo_manage(content);
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: maybe http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/setting-default-schema-working-for-xml-refactorings-but-not-sql ?

Answer (score 2):

As @pozs has pointed out, there's a solution here:
https://forum.liquibase.org/topic/setting-default-schema-working-for-xml-refactorings-but-not-sql

So the code that make this work would be

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("dataSource")
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
  SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
  liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
  liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:META-INF/liquibase/application-changes.xml");
  liquibase.setContexts("default"); 
  liquibase.setDefaultSchema(databaseProperties.getJdbcSchema());
  liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(createChangeLogParameters());
  return liquibase;
```

}

```
private Map<String, String> createChangeLogParameters() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("defaultSchema", databaseProperties.getJdbcSchema()); // needed on SQL in <sql> tags.
    return map;
}
```

And here the Liquibase:

```
<changeSet id="xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-postgres" runInTransaction="true" failOnError="true"
onValidationFail="HALT" dbms="postgresql">
<sql >
    CREATE TRIGGER t_table BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON ${defaultSchema}.table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ${defaultSchema}.lo_manage(content);
</sql>
```